# how to set image and text scroll in adobe capivate 9

Tags: adobe-captivate

Can anyone please help me. Am using adobe captivate 9. I have a content with image that exceeds the slide spacing, i want to set this content within the page using scroll. I have tried using text-scroll widget but i cant add images to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image into an MS Word document and save it as an HTML web page. The result will be an HTML file and folder named "[file name]_files" in whichever folder you saved it to.

Select both the HTML file and the folder, right click, and choose **Send to** -> **Compressed (zipped) folder** in the context menu.

Dragging that ZIP folder directly onto your Captivate slide will create scrolling HTML Web Object based on the formatting of the MS Word file. It will show up in your Library in the "Web" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a feature that is missing from Captivate. The best solution I've found is to make an html file that includes the text and points to the image, then zip and import as an HTML5 Animation.